# Permissions Levels

Tags: permissions

I am attempting to create a list where I want a customer to be able to see everything but not be able to edit certain columns. I am on sharepoint online and do not have the permissions myself to create a custom permission for this. Do I need to have someone create this for me or is there another way to do this?

Comment: The administrator of the site has to do it. If you want to set permission, then you should have the admin rights.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: You cannot restrict to edit columns, you can only restrict to edit the whole item.

Answer (score 1):

To change the permission sets you need to have full rights or be a site collection administrator.  However, as @unnie stated, you can't control permission on a per column / field basis directly with SharePoint.

There are a few ways to approach this that I can think of:

1. Create a custom form and push data to list - this gives you most control and you can hide the list you are writing too.  You can use JavaScript or CSOM to accomplish this.
2. Modify the editform.aspx page for the list and disable the input boxes - drop a CEWP or Script web part on the page and use JavaScript / CSS to disable the input boxes.
3. Make use of multiple lists and workflows.  Assuming the users are not the original authors you can grant read only access to the "source" list, and give them write access to the destination list.  When they make changes - check those changes against the source and if any column values you don't want changed don't match - write back the appropriate value.

Comment: The first two work for many companies, but they involve "hiding" the fields, not securing them. A power user will have no difficulty getting around either of these.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, that can be helpful depending on your scenario: 
Create another list, which is only editable by admins. Link this list items to the rows in the other list by using row Id for instance, or any other foreign key.

Display the info using Javascript CSOM for instance, and create a custom form.